# add tags to aws dynamo db

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to powershell and wants to know if there is way to tag Dynamo DB table (name: Testname) from powershell.
I did try these commands:  Add-DDBResourceTag -ResourceArn $dbarn -Tag @{Key="Department";Value="Stage"}
where $dbarn is arn of DBtable 'Testname'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag should be created as an object in powershell of type Amazon.Dynamodbv2.Model.Tag

Something like this

```
$Tagobject = New-Object Amazon.Dynamodbv2.Model.Tag
$Tagobject.Key = "Environment"
$Tagobject.Value = "Prod"
```

You can then use your command

```
Add-DDBResourceTag -ResourceArn $dbarn -Tag $Tagobject
```

Comment: what if i have to add environment and Status tags also Like : Environment : prod and Status : UP, Region : us-east-1 (i am sorry, This is new for me)